# Templates add string to the front

Tags: django

In my templates, I can use the `|add:'xx'` to add string to the templates string.

```
<body>
    <form action="/cookie/fm/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="text" name="username"> {{ obj.errors.username.0 | add:' -- error --' }} </p>
        <p><input type="text" name="pwd"> {{ obj.errors.pwd.0 }} </p>
        <p><input type="text" name="email"> {{ obj.errors.email.0 }} </p>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

But you know it is add at the end, how can I add the string in the front ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom template tag. Create a file named `<appname>\templatetags\<appname>_extras.py` and put this code in the file.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def addstr(arg1, arg2):
    """concatenate arg1 & arg2"""
    return str(arg2) + str(arg1)
```

You can use this template tag in the same way you are using add template tag. You can look for [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/)